# How do you integrate Microsoft Account into a Windows Store App?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-account

I'm writing an app which accesses user information over the web. I want to use the Microsoft Account of the current user, to identify them to my application and, in turn, to the cloud-hosted services supporting the application. If they don't have an account, I would prompt them to create one.

In short, I would like functionality much like the Games hub of Windows 8, but I haven't found any tutorials on user identity that could start me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826551.aspx should be what you want to do. It's the same tutorial i used to enable sign in with microsoft account in my app.